# Make Vim Curly Braces, Square Braces, Parens act like Textmate

Tags: vim

So I guess I'm not searching for the right thing but I'm looking to see how you can get VIM to act like Textmate when it comes to writing a set of curly braces, parens, or square brackets hit enter and you get this. Pipe indicates cursor.

```
      function doSomething(){
          |
      }

      #selector{
          |
      }
```

Instead of this garbage

```
      function doSomething(){
      |}

      #selector{
      |}
```

I already have the [{( closing each other when they are typed just the return and indentation is jacked. As usual any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I use the following mappings in my `.vimrc`:

```
inoremap {<cr> {<cr>}<c-o>O<tab>
inoremap [<cr> [<cr>]<c-o>O<tab>
inoremap (<cr> (<cr>)<c-o>O<tab>
```

So when I input:

```
function foo(){<cr>
```

I get:

```
function foo(){
    |
}
```

Similar with `(<cr>` and `[<cr>`.

Comment: thank you man ,, but I want the cursor closer ,,, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105891/i-want-to-do-vim-snipmate-like-textmate

Comment: The cursor's position is dictated by your `tabstop` & Co. settings in your .vimrc. Randy's is set to 4, mine is set to 2. You can set it to whatever value you want.

Comment: I wish I could up-vote this twice! Not only did it solve the issue but it taught me about <c-o> in remap commands.

Comment: I removed the <tab> tag at the end and I have smartindent as well in .vimrc. Curly braces are added and the caret is put in the right spot. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

### A note to delimitMate users

When using the [delimitMate](https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate) plugin, the mappings of the other answers interfere with the plugin. Luckily, this behavior is already available in delimitMate (but disabled by default), by setting the `delmitMateExpansion` options. E.g. add

```
let delimitMate_expand_cr = 1
```

to your `.vimrc`

Comment: delimitMate is a great plugin and does this without a remap.  +1

Answer (score 4):

This is my modification of Randy Moris' answer that works better for me:

```
inoremap {<cr> {<cr>}<c-o><s-o>
inoremap [<cr> [<cr>]<c-o><s-o>
inoremap (<cr> (<cr>)<c-o><s-o>
```

Comment: I also map fot `({ })` with `inoremap ({<cr> ({<cr>})<c-o><s-o>`

Answer (score 1):

My solution for this was to put this little function (with corresponding insert-mode mapping) in my .vimrc:

```
fun! MyCR()
    if strpart(getline('.'), col('.') - 2, 2) == '{}'
        return "\<CR>\<CR>\<Up>\<Tab>"
    endif
    return "\<CR>"
endfun
autocmd FileType c,cpp inoremap <CR> <C-R>=MyCR()<CR>
```

You can change the autocmd so that it will work for your preferred file types.

It remaps `<CR>` in insert mode to check if the cursor is currently inside curly braces and adds the extra line and indentation where appropriate.

Comment: And as usually: the only right way to do it is at the bottom and has 0 upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you like Text make you should check [Vim plugin, snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540), as indicated by tarek11011.

For C/C++ it has by default a snippet for functions

```
# Function
snippet fun
   ${1:void} ${2:function_name}(${3}) {
      ${4:/* code */}
   }
```

, which would solve the curly braces issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following on my .vimrc

```
  imap {<Space> {<Space><Space>}<left><left>
  imap { {<CR>}
  imap {<CR> {<CR><CR>}<Up>;<Esc>==i

  imap ( ()
  imap () ()
  inoremap <silent> (. ().<C-x><C-o>
  inoremap <silent> (- ()-><C-x><C-o>
  imap (<space> (<space><space>)<left><left>

  imap [ []
  imap [<space> [<space><space>]<left><left>

  inoremap " ""<left>
  inoremap "" ""
```

ok, explanations:
when you hit {, sometimes you want to break a line and put and ending }, but sometimes you just want to stay in the same line, just like: a = {1,2,3};

`#` means where the cursor is:

So when you hit `{` and just after that you hit space -> `{ # }`
when you hit `{` after a little delay or any other than space is used the line will be break
when you hit `{` just after an enter, the code will be:

```
foo(){
   #
}
```

When you hit `(.` results in `().<call to omnicomplete>` Just line namespace::Singleton::Create().

You have to use `inoremap` with `"`, to avoid infinite """""""""""""""""""""""

Answer (score 0):

Here's my key mapping.

```
inoremap <expr><Cr> "<Cr>" . (strpart(getline('.'), col('.') - 2, 2) =~# '\[\]\<Bar>{}\<Bar>()' ? "<Esc>O" : "")
```

1. `strpart(getline('.'), col('.') - 2, 2)` means getting surrounding characters. For example, `{|}`(where `|` is your cursor in insert mode), will return `{}`.
2. `'\[\]\<Bar>{}\<Bar>()'` is a regular expression in VimSript. It means matching `[]` or `{}` or `()`. I use `<Bar>` in case of escaping.
3. In my case, `O` will have auto-indentation so I use a simple `<Esc>O`. You can adjust to make it suit with your request.

Answer (score -2):

I have `set ai` in my vimrc which I believe does what you want?

Comment: Autoindenting just does the indenting automatically for you, the problem is how Vim understands the indenting is supposed to work.