# I want to do vim snipMate like TextMate

Tags: vim, plugins, textmate, snipmate

i use vim with [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) But I find this problem

```
if (true) {|};
```

in TextMate After pressing Enter key .. Look at the cursor

```
if (true) {
    |
};
```

in vim After pressing Enter key .. Look at the cursor

```
if (true) {
|};
```

How to Make vim , such as TextMate

thanks

***edit***

this is my vimrc

```
filetype on                   " Enable filetype detection
filetype indent on            " Enable filetype-specific indenting
filetype plugin on            " Enable filetype-specific plugins

" New Tab
nnoremap <silent> <C-t> :tabnew<CR>
" Next Tab
nnoremap <silent> <C-Right> :tabnext<CR>

" Previous Tab
nnoremap <silent> <C-Left> :tabprevious<CR>

abbrev ff :! Open -a Firefox.app %:p<cr>

abbrev gc :! Open -a Chrome.app %:p<cr>
" Set off the other paren
highlight MatchParen ctermbg=4
" }}}

"{{{Look and Feel

" Favorite Color Scheme

   colorscheme sunburst

   set guioptions-=T

" When I close a tab, remove the buffer
set nohidden


" Highlight things that we find with the search
set hlsearch



" Incremental searching is sexy
set incsearch


" This is totally awesome - remap jj to escape in insert mode.  You'll never type jj anyway, so it's great!
inoremap jj <Esc>


" And so is Artificial Intellegence!
set smartcase


" Enable mouse support in console
set mouse=a

" Got backspace?
set backspace=2

" Line Numbers PWN!
set number

" Ignoring case is a fun trick
set ignorecase



" Who wants an 8 character tab?  Not me!
set shiftwidth=3
set softtabstop=3


" Spaces are better than a tab character
set expandtab
set smarttab

" Who doesn't like autoindent?
set autoindent
set smartindent
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab


" Needed for Syntax Highlighting and stuff
filetype on
filetype plugin on
syntax enable
set grepprg=grep\ -nH\ $*

set foldmethod=indent
set foldnestmax=10
set nofoldenable
set foldlevel=1

" This shows what you are typing as a command.  I love this!
set showcmd

set cul                                           
hi CursorLine term=none cterm=none ctermbg=3      
set tabstop=2
set ruler                     " show the line number on the bar
set autoread                  " watch for file changes
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set cmdheight=2               " command line two lines high
set undolevels=1000           " 1000 undos
"map a change directory in desktop
nmap ,d :cd C:\Users\Tarek\Desktop<cr>:e.<cr>


""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Visual mode related
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Really useful!
"  In visual mode when you press * or # to search for the current selection
vnoremap <silent> * :call VisualSearch('f')<CR>
vnoremap <silent> # :call VisualSearch('b')<CR>

" When you press gv you vimgrep after the selected text
vnoremap <silent> gv :call VisualSearch('gv')<CR>
map <leader>g :vimgrep // **/*.<left><left><left><left><left><left><left>


function! CmdLine(str)
    exe "menu Foo.Bar :" . a:str
    emenu Foo.Bar
    unmenu Foo
endfunction

" From an idea by Michael Naumann
function! VisualSearch(direction) range
    let l:saved_reg = @"
    execute "normal! vgvy"

    let l:pattern = escape(@", '\\/.*$^~[]')
    let l:pattern = substitute(l:pattern, "\n$", "", "")

    if a:direction == 'b'
        execute "normal ?" . l:pattern . "^M"
    elseif a:direction == 'gv'
        call CmdLine("vimgrep " . '/'. l:pattern . '/' . ' **/*.')
    elseif a:direction == 'f'
        execute "normal /" . l:pattern . "^M"
    endif

    let @/ = l:pattern
    let @" = l:saved_reg
endfunction

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Command mode related
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Smart mappings on the command line
cno $h e ~/
cno $d e ~/Desktop/
cno $j e ./
cno $c e <C-\>eCurrentFileDir("e")<cr>
cno $u e ftp://learnsto@ftp.learn-store.com/www/


" $q is super useful when browsing on the command line
cno $q <C-\>eDeleteTillSlash()<cr>

" Bash like keys for the command line
cnoremap <C-A>      <Home>
cnoremap <C-E>      <End>
cnoremap <C-K>      <C-U>

cnoremap <C-P> <Up>
cnoremap <C-N> <Down>

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

"Opens file in buffer in Chrome
abbrev ch :! @start "" /b "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" %:p
"Opens file in buffer in Firefox
abbrev fc :! @start "" /b "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" %:p


""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

imap <C-e> <C-y>,
imap <C-j> <C-x><C-o>
"" set guifont=Inconsolata\ 16
set nocp
    if version >= 600
      filetype plugin indent on
    endif
    let g:netrw_alto = 1

" Use menu to show command-line completion (in 'full' case)
set wildmenu

" Set command-line completion mode:
"   - on first <Tab>, when more than one match, list all matches and complete
"     the longest common  string
"   - on second <Tab>, complete the next full match and show menu
set wildmode=list:longest,full

" Show the bookmarks table on startup
let NERDTreeShowBookmarks=1
let b:surround_indent = 1
au BufRead,BufNewFile jquery.*.js set ft=javascript syntax=jquery

let g:js_indent_log = 0
```

Comment: The 3 last lines make me think that you load an alternative syntax script (and probably an alternative indent script as well), maybe it overrides your .vimrc settings. There is also a duplicated setting (`set tabstop`) with two different values, I don't thinks it's a problem but it's dirty.

Comment: @romainl ok I modified vimrc but Nothing happens ,, delete duplicated and delete 3 last lines

Comment: What language are you coding with? Both my php.snippets and my javascript.snippets have slightly different `if` snippets but both already have the `{}` pair correctly expanded with the cursor indented and on a line of its own. If you _actually_ type the whole snippet you may be interested in [this q/a]() or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066372/make-vim-curly-braces-square-braces-parens-act-like-textmate).

Comment: Don't take it badly, but judging by your question history I think you are really struggling with Vim (and its indentation system) since at least a few months. TextMate is quite powerful as is - I know, I've been using it for years - so what draws to Vim?

Comment: In what language/filetype did you found the problem? You can find out which filetype by opening the file and issuing `:set ft?`. You could also post your snippet file for that filetype (usually at ~/.vim/snippets/ - *nix or $HOME/vimfiles/snippets  - mswindows).

Answer (score 1):

Put this into your .vimrc file:

```
inoremap {<cr> {<CR><CR>}<Esc>-cc
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a SnipMate problem but an indentation problem. probably related to `set autoindent`. For me it works as you want.

Here are all my indentation related settings:

```
" a tab is 2 spaces
set tabstop=2
" when hitting <BS>, pretend like a tab is removed, even     if spaces
set softtabstop=2
" expand tabs by default (overloadable per file type later)
set expandtab
" number of spaces to use for autoindenting
set shiftwidth=2
" use multiple of shiftwidth when indenting with '<' and '>'
set shiftround
" always set autoindenting on
set autoindent
" copy the previous indentation on autoindenting
set copyindent
" insert tabs on the start of a line according to
" shiftwidth, not tabstop
set smarttab
```

Comment: thanks romainl ,, I added my .vimrc Please look at it and tell me where the error