# How can I automatically create a new line when editing CSS in vim? (like textmate)

Tags: vim, macvim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make Vim Curly Braces, Square Braces, Parens act like Textmate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066372/make-vim-curly-braces-square-braces-parens-act-like-textmate)

I'm coming from textmate and I'm really really loving vim.

One part I liked about textmate was when editing css you would type

```
.title {
```

and it would auto complete the brackets to this (where | is the cursor)...

```
.title {|}
```

THen you would hit enter and it turns to

```
.title {
    |
}
```

I have the "Autoclose" plugin but when you hit enter it just brings the } with it and looks like a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try an imap:

```
:imap { {<Esc>o}<Esc>ko
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [nice Vim plugin, snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540), that provides auto-completion and maybe can attend your needs.

By default it works for bigger patterns, as the entire tag `.title` in your example. Maybe you could insert a snippet for '{'.