# How can I autoclose brackets in vim?

Tags: vim

I'm starting to do a lot of coding with vim, particularly C. While I've added some tricks to my vimrc file for code colour formatting, line numbers, etc., I'm wondering if there's a way to achieve the following functionality:

This -

```
int main() {
```

becomes this -

```
int main() {

}
```

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions? I'll give anything a try as long as it saves me from forgetting another bracket ever again!

Comment: I haven't used this but I think this maybe what your looking for: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1849

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make Vim Curly Braces, Square Braces, Parens act like Textmate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066372/make-vim-curly-braces-square-braces-parens-act-like-textmate)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a bunch of plugins for doing that "smartly": [autoclose](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2009), [closepairs](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2373), [others…](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=pair&script_type=&order_by=creation_date&direction=descending&search=search) I use [delimitmate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2754).

But you can also go the lo-tech way:

```
inoremap { {<cr>}<C-o>O
```

Answer (score 2):

9 years later but for posterity I tried to cover all cases with the following mappings, just put them in your .vimrc

```
" # Close brackets automatically, with return
inoremap {<cr> {<cr>}<C-O><S-O>
inoremap (<cr> (<cr>)<c-o><s-o>
inoremap [<cr> [<cr>]<c-o><s-o>
" # Close brackets without return
inoremap ( ()<left>
inoremap { {}<left>
inoremap [ []<left>
" # Two cases below are covered by inoremap <exp>
" inoremap " ""<left>
" inoremap ' ''<left>
" # If you close a bracket that is already closed, it overwrites
inoremap <expr> ) strpart(getline('.'), col('.')-1, 1) == ")" ? "\<Right>" : ")"
inoremap <expr> } strpart(getline('.'), col('.')-1, 1) == "}" ? "\<Right>" : "}"
inoremap <expr> ] strpart(getline('.'), col('.')-1, 1) == "]" ? "\<Right>" : "]"
inoremap <expr> ' strpart(getline('.'), col('.')-1, 1) == "'" ? "\<Right>" : "''<left>"
inoremap <expr> " strpart(getline('.'), col('.')-1, 1) == "\"" ? "\<Right>" : "\"\"<left>"
" # enclose a word in normal mode with "'({[
nnoremap ' mmbi'<esc>ea'<esc>`m<right>
nnoremap " mmbi"<esc>ea"<esc>`m<right>
nnoremap ( mmbi(<esc>ea)<esc>`m<right>
nnoremap { mmbi{<esc>ea}<esc>`m<right>
nnoremap [ mmbi[<esc>ea]<esc>`m<right>
" # enclose a selection in visual mode with "'({[
vnoremap ' <Esc>`<i'<Esc>`>a<right>'<Esc>
vnoremap " <Esc>`<i"<Esc>`>a<right>"<Esc>
vnoremap ( <Esc>`<i(<Esc>`>a<right>)<Esc>
vnoremap { <Esc>`<i{<Esc>`>a<right>}<Esc>
vnoremap [ <Esc>`<i[<Esc>`>a<right>]<Esc>
```